# How to union objects from different levels?

Tags: json, jq

I have this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "cnt": 45543336
    }
  },
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "cnt": 59389530
    }
  },
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "cnt": 58390082
    }
  }
]
```

And I need to convert it to this result. That is, union the inner level with the outer level, for each object in the array:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "cnt": 45543336
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "cnt": 59389530
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "cnt": 58390082
  }
]
```

The part I'm having trouble with is how to get `timestamp` to be in the same object as `cnt`. Then I can remove unneeded properties.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add them?

```
map({timestamp} + .event)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LtSqfnd9gs)</sup>